# Rails Concern dynamic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I write a gem for rails to have a tiny mongoid shopping cart.

in the models it get's implemented by including `include MongoidCart::ActsAsProduct`

```
class MyProduct
   include Mongoid::Document

   include MongoidCart::ActsAsProduct
end


module MongoidCart
  class CartItem
    include Mongoid::Document

    belongs_to :mongoid_cart_cart, :class_name => 'MongoidCart::Cart'
  end
end


module MongoidCart
  class Cart
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :user_id, type: String

    has_many :cart_items, :inverse_of => :cart, :class_name => 'MongoidCart::CartItem'
    belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :carts, :class_name => MongoidCart.configuration.customer_model_name

  end
end
```

I have troubles to bring in the `class_name` of my `Product`-class to the `CartItem`-class.
It should do automatically add a relation to the `MongoidCart::CartItem`class. 
When I "hardcode" as `:my_product` I have, no errors.

#### How can I make the `:the_class_to_point_to_as_symbol` dynamic?

```
module MongoidCart
  module ActsAsProduct
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do

      #adds dynamic association to the CartItem to refer to the ActsAsProduct class
      MongoidCart::CartItem.class_eval(
        'belongs_to :the_class_to_point_to_as_symbol, :class_name => "Product", inverse_of: :cart_item'
      )
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by creating a new class which produces the String, which gets interpreted by `class_eval` and call them outside of the scope and place the string in a variable:

```
module MongoidCart
  module ActsAsProduct
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do

      # adds dynamic association to the CartItem to refer to the ActsAsProduct class
      relation_method = MongoidCart::Relation.build_product_relation_string(name)
      MongoidCart::CartItem.class_eval(relation_method)
  end
end



module MongoidCart
  class Relation

    # creates a string which can be implemented in models to provide dynamcic relation
    def self.build_product_relation_string(class_name)
      "belongs_to "+ ":#{class_name.to_s.underscore.to_sym}" + ", :class_name => '#{class_name.constantize}', inverse_of: :cart_item"
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` inside `included{}` block is the included class, so you can do something like

```
included do
  MongoidCart::CartItem.add_product_relation(self)
end
```

MongoidCart::CartItem:

```
def self.add_product_relation cls
  belongs_to cls.name.to_s.underscore.to_sym, class_name:cls, inverse_of: :cart_item
end
```